# Wordpress Theme Customization error

Tags: theme-customizer

On customizing Newspaper theme in Wordpress the page stops loading. [image]

Following errors can be seen in the console. I disabled all the plugins to check if it's a problem with any of them. But still, the issue existed. Any clue would be appreciated. My website is hosted on wordpress.com.

Comment: Enable wp-debug and let us know what is says.
https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find out the reason for the problem. But asked the WordPress chat support and they said they just reset the jetpack support on WordPress and it worked after that.